# Take row wise percentages on power BI tables

Tags: powerbi, percentage, tabular

I Have the following table on power BI:

[image]

For which I have to take the percentages by of each category by class, but when a show the values as percentages of the total on power BI I get the following:

[image]

Which is a column wise percentage, how can I get it this way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you unpivot those columns, in the query editor so that your data is shaped like this:

```
Class  Attribute Value
A      Aproved   10
A      Reproved  10
B      Aproved    3
B      Reproved   2
C      Aproved    2
C      Reproved   9
D      Aproved    3
D      Reproved   1
```

Then it's as simple as putting `Class` on rows, `Attribute` on columns and setting the implicit measure for `Value` to Percent of row total.

[image: Row totals]